# Exclude section from handouts

Tags: beamer, overlays

I want to exclude a whole section of my beamer presentation in the handout version. Frames and content can be hidden using the overlay specifier `<handout:0>`. But how do I hide the `\section` to not have an empty chapter in the table of contents and bookmarks? `\mode<beamer>{\section{Section}}` works, but how do I specify that it should not only be visible in `beamer` mode but in all modes apart from `handout`?

Comment: could you comment it?

Comment: Obviously, the section is gone when commented. But the section should be only hidden in `handout` mode and still be visible with all slides belonging to it in other modes.

Comment: so could you consider to edit the TOC entry directly? but this method is not wise, I admit that.

Comment: see if enclosing the entire section in `\only<beamer>{...}` works (you need to compile twice)

Comment: Thanks for fixing my wording error. There is no mode `presentation`. `\only<beamer>` works as well as `\mode<beamer>`. But now how to specify all modes apart from `handout`?

Comment: there is a `presentation` mode, take a look at section 21.3 of the beamer manual for more details. You can specify more than one mode, so if you want all except handout just add the others: `\only<beamer|article|second|trans>{...}`

Comment: So there is no possibility to specify something like `\only<not handout>` for this case like `\only<handout:0>` can be used inside frames?

Answer (score 2):

The following exclude the section from `handout` mode:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\mode<handout:0>{\section{Section}\frame{f}}

\end{document}
```